# Find state space model from transfer function

Tags: fourier-transform, transfer-function, laplace-transform

Let's suppose we have:

G(s) = (s+1)/(s^2-2s+1)

how can we find the state space representation of the transfer function:

x_dot = x2

x2_dot = 2*x2-x1+u

where u is an arbitrary input.

I am very new to this topic, so a detailed answere would be great ! :)

Comment: Hint. The laplace operator roughly speaking performs derivatives. If you have $y/u=G(s)$, how can you substitute the "s" with derivatives?

Comment: @LjSilver Hmmm... I am sorry, could you help me a bit...

Comment: @LJSilver see my comment above. Help is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, assuming that the transfer function is between the output $Y(s)$ and the input $U(s)$, namely
$$
\dfrac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = G(s)\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
multiplying (1) by $U(s)\cdot(s^2-2s+1))$ yields
$$
s^2 Y(s) -2s Y(s) + Y(s) = sU(s) + U(s)
$$
Going back in the time domain we obtain
$$
\ddot y -2\dot y + y = \dot u + u\qquad (2)
$$
Now, we look for a realization of the kind
\begin{align*}
\dot x &= Ax+Bu\qquad (3)\\
y &=Cx
\end{align*}
with $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and
\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\a_1 & a_2\end{pmatrix} & B&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}, & C&=\begin{pmatrix}c_1&c_2\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}
The next step is to find the values of $(a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2)$ for which (3) has the same input-output behaviour of (2). From (3) we have
\begin{align*}
 y&=c_1x_1+c_2x_2\\
\dot y&= c_1\dot x_1 + c_2\dot x_2 = c_1x_2 + c_2a_1x_1 + c_2a_2 x_2 + c_2u\\
\ddot y&= c_1\ddot x_1 + c_2\ddot x_2 = c_1a_1x_1+c_1a_2x_2 +c_1u+ c_2a_1x_2+ c_2a_2a_1x_1+c_2a_2^2 x_2 + c_2a_2u + c_2\dot u
\end{align*}
substituting into (2) yields
\begin{align*}
0&=(c_1+c_1a_1+c_2a_2a_1-2c_2a_1)x_1 + (c_2+c_1a_2+c_2a_1+c_2a_2^2-2c_1-2c_2a_2)x_2\\
&+(c_1+a_2c_2-2c_2-1)u + (c_2-1)\dot u
\end{align*}
since that equality must hold for all $(x_1,x_2,u,\dot u)$ that' equivalent to ask
\begin{align*}
c_1+c_1a_1+c_2a_2a_1-2c_2a_1&=0\\c_2+c_1a_2+c_2a_1+c_2a_2^2-2c_1-2c_2a_2&=0\\
c_1+a_2c_2-2c_2-1&=0\\c_2-1&=0
\end{align*}
and a solution is
$$
(a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2)=(-1,2,1,1)
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\end{pmatrix} &=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\\y&=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That was very clear. My prof. sometimes uses Y/U = Y/X*X/U, then says  (s+1)/(s^2-2s+1) =   (s+1)*1/(s^2-2s+1), hence Y/X=s+1 and X/U = s^2-2s+1, he then transforms it back to Time domain and hence finds the state space representation. Do you see why he can do it like that ?

Comment: Yes, you can proceed also in that way. In that way you obtain two models, the first with input u and output x, the second with input x and output y. Then you just have to consider their interconnectio

Comment: @totyped You also have to keep in mind that a state space model of a given transfer function is not unique (there are infinity many state space models which correspond to the same transfer function).